# Parse string to json with string mixed

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse a string var to json object, however it is not json all the time. If it is not json I want it to be returned as it. I tried JSON.parse, but it will post error when the var is pure string, finally I got JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(var)), I wonder whether there is a way to judge a string can be parse to json or not, so I can save the "stingify" phase.

Comment: did you try, "try / catch" ?

Comment: Do you know what general format the string will have, if it is not JSON? If you absolutely must avoid the JSON.parse step, you can try a heuristic based on checking to see if the string is in this non-JSON format first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no better way than actually parsing and knowing if its valid or not. You can use `try`/`catch` blocks to set the variable and then return it.

```
function toJSON(str) {
    var rtn;
    try { rtn = JSON.parse(str); }  // try to set it
    catch (e) { rtn = str; } // if error set it to str
    return rtn;  // finally return
}
```

Comment: again return caught exception `rtn = e.toString();` msg would be more meaningful

Comment: @Girish it won't be. That's not what OP wants

Comment: it's non sense `rtn = str;`

Comment: @Girish yup. Common sense is not so common.

Comment: This is not the most elegant answer, but it seems try catch is the reasonable one. Thanks!

Comment: @sayume I do think it is an elegant answer, however glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use try / catch. if you get exception when you try to parse it, it means that it is not valid json

```
var victim=....;
var output;
try { 
   output = JSON.parse(victim); 
} catch (e) { 
   output = victim;
}
```